# Create LinkColumn with dynamic link

Tags: django-tables2

How do I dynamically pass a viewname to LinkColumn, depending on the request URL?
For example:

```
# called from example.com/foo
col = LinkColumn('foo_detail', args=[A('id')])

# called from example.com/bar
col = LinkColumn('bar_detail', args=[A('id')])
```

I could do something link this from the `__init__()` method but I need the request object to decide which viewname I need to pass to the LinkColumn and this is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting use case, I don't think there is a straightforward way to do so currently.

A workaround would be to use `get_absolute_url` on the model's you are displaying, if those are different between the views. If you pass `viewname=None` to `LinkColumn`, it will use the url from `record.get_absolute_url()`.

The most pragmatic way to fix this would be a `TemplateColumn` with a small template to implement the different urls.